# Converting items in lists to a float

Tags: python

I am creating a calculator and I place the numbers taken by the user into a list.I had to make the input a string since I place the input in a `while` loop and gave it a string to break the loop (`q`).

```
while True:
    numbers = input('Enter the numbers for calculation: ')
    if numbers == 'q':
        break
    operations.append(numbers)
```

I want to turn the list where the user's input is kept into a float so that I can perform operations on them.
This is the list: `operations = []`

Comment: `operations.append(float(numbers))` assuming you are introducing the numbers one by one and they are indeed valid numbers (except for the "q" character)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse a string to a float or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still learning Python, so don't judge too harshly.

```
operations = []
while:
    number = input('Enter number\n')

    if number == 'q':
        print('QUIT')
        break
    else:
        number = float(int(number))
        operations.append(number)
        print(operations)
```

I just couldn't make a check for the input of any other letters, except for "q"